# Brightcove - change or hide a video name programmatically

Tags: brightcove

Can I change or hide a video name programmatically for a Brightcove video player?

Comment: Try checking here: http://forum.brightcove.com/t5/Flash-Only-Player-APIs/Chenge-video-title/m-p/1774/highlight/true#M438

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the Video's name (aka display_name) using the Brightcove Media API's update_video method: http://docs.brightcove.com/en/media/samples/update_video.html

If you want to change the name on the client-side and not have it be permanent, you can follow this example for changing the video's name: http://docs.brightcove.com/en/smart-player-api/samples/update-media.html